# Access cookies from http request

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I tried to access a cookie saved by our web application from a C# winform application. I can see the saved cookie from within the chrome developer tool, but in my winform application, the cookie container always returns 0 cookies. Not sure what I did wrong.

Any help and input are greatly appreciated!

Here is the cookie out web application saved
[image]

Here is the code to try to read cookie, and it always returns 0 cookies.
[image]

```cs
static void Main()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost");
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            foreach (Cookie cky in response.Cookies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cky.Name + " = " + cky.Value);
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new PrintJobQueue());
        }
```

here is the request/response from Fiddler
[image]

Here is the cookie in setting view of Chrome:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any debuggable code?

Comment: Thank you for your help, John and I added the C# code

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

Comment: You will only have a cookie if it has had been set on the WinForms application request. The fact you can see it in Chrome does not mean your code can. How is the web app setting a cookie - via a login page?. Try using a proxy like Fiddler to check the actual request and response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, ste-fu. the cookie is set when a user browser to a certain page of our application. I'll try to use Fiddler to double check the request/response.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330142/Cookie-Quest-A-Quest-to-Read-Cookies-from-Four-Pop

Comment: Is there a reason why the Fiddler request connects to `http://localhost:4300`, but your C# code connects to `http://localhost` (i.e. port 80)?

Comment: thanks John. that could be a typo, it is http://localhost:4300, but I got same result (0 cookies returned).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, marcoaoteixeira. Here is the query string I used to get my cookie,:

sql = "SELECT value FROM cookies WHERE host_key LIKE '%localhost%' AND name LIKE '%recentAccessedLoanNumber%';"

I got the reader back based on the sample code, the value is always empty string, also I can see it in Chrome's setting page (the value is 3096) as in the screen shot.

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: marcoaoteixeira, I figured it out. Instead of "select value ...", I should use "select encrypted_value ..." and then decrypt it. That worked!

Thanks a lot for your help again!